# slow select query on datetime column

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a table in MySQL which has approximately 10 million records, and now a query which used to take micro seconds now takes more that 8 seconds to execute!
Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `runs` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `runstub` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rundata` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=10039971 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and here is the query that takes more than 8 secs...

```
SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM runs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10000
```

Is there a way I can optimise this query to get it run in less than a second?

This is the result I want to achieve: From the last 10k records (not all), the time it took. I want the time it started (`MIN(created_at)`) and the time it ended (`MAX(created_at)`). How can I achieve that without the limit?

Comment: Your query does not do what the description wants it to do.  You must change to something like Lennart's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one attempt:

```
SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) 
FROM (
    SELECT created_at
    FROM runs 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 10000
) as x;
```

Your query is evaluated as:

```
SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM runs
```

Then it is ordered according to id (which doesn't make sense) and a maximum of 10000 rows is returned (only 1 row exists)

My query first picks the 10000 most recent id's

```
SELECT created_at
FROM runs 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10000
```

From there it picks min and max for created_at

Answer (score -1):

if the query used to take microseconds and now takes minutes means you reach a limit... probably query buffer.

Check your my.cnf file and increase or set the following params

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
max_connections         = 4096
sort_buffer_size        = 32M
read_buffer_size        = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 8M
wait_timeout            = 10
connect_timeout         = 5
interactive_timeout     = 10
concurrent_insert       = 2
thread_concurrency      = 0
tmp_table_size          = 64M
max_heap_table_size     = 512M
```

Comment: None of these are relevant.  Do not tweak any of them.  The "Query cache" could explain the difference.